# Can't we simulate nosql key value pair databases by RDBMS

Tags: redis, cassandra, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have read that one of the advantages (among others) of using Amazon DynamoDB is that we can just convert Java objects in XML/JSON and store as values in nosql database. But can't we just serialize the java object in a string and have an RDBMS simulate key value nosql database by a 2 fields table -- key and varchar/blob . The varchar can store the serialized string. Is this quoted benefit wrongly said?.

Also, RDBMS can be distributed as well, so can be scalable. So the only benefit of using nosql I see is letting go of having each transaction comply with ACID thus making operations faster. Is this the only advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distributed RDBMS is a complex thing. Because it can support data that is not key/value but more complex interrelated tables, it becomes very difficult to split up data in an optimal way. There is no way to do this optimally for all types of queries you might want to run against that data.

Whereas if it's key/value data, the types of queries you can run are simpler, and therefore the problem space is a lot simpler. It becomes easier to be sure you have split up the data in a way that won't harm your queries, because your queries are mostly lookups by key anyway. As long as you can deterministically map a query by key to the node that the key lives on, your queries remain optimized.

Also, expansion is easier. Adding a new node to your cluster involves remapping which keys live on which nodes, but that can be done more easily in a key/value store. There are no foreign keys to keep track of.

Key/value stores are easier to scale because they don't try to enforce ACID properties or data integrity that an RDBMS does.

You suppose that if you just use an RDBMS as if it were just a key/value store, you could do those things, and that's true. But the RDBMS software is designed under the assumption that you *may* need ACID and data integrity, so it enforces those things by default.

Could an RDBMS be designed to serve either workload, and have configuration parameters to fully disable ACID and data integrity? Sure. If you find an RDBMS that is implemented with those kinds of configuration options, feel free to use it as a key/value store. (I don't know of one.)

Or you could just use a key/value store that is designed around that concept from the beginning. You don't have to coerce a key/value store into mimicking a key/value store.

This is why different technologies exist — they are optimized for different types of work. It's the same reason there are different types of screw heads. None are "better" than the other, they're designed for different jobs. Each is more or less a poor substitute for the job that the others do well.

[image]

Comment: Love the screw head analogy.  I'm definitely going to remember/reuse that one!